# Maven doesn't see tested classes

Tags: unit-testing, maven-2

i have problem with maven. When i try to compile test classes (`mvn test-compile`), it fails to find the tested classes used in test classes. For example class `UserTest` can't be compiled because compiler can't find class `User` which is being used inside the `UserTest` class. The problem is most likely in the class path not including target folder during `test-compile` phase, which is weird because i thought maven does include it.

If anyone had any ideas how to fix this issue, i would be greatful.

The pom.xml file can be found here http://github.com/tomasherman/JBTBackup/blob/master/pom.xml, just like rest of the project.

The maven output is as follows:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building JBTBackup Maven Webapp
[INFO]    task-segment: [test-compile]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[WARNING] While downloading hibernate:hibernate:3.0.5
  This artifact has been relocated to org.hibernate:hibernate:3.0.5.


[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/resources
[INFO] [sql:execute {execution: add-test-data}]
[INFO] Executing file: /tmp/pre-test-editdb.1278025605sql
[INFO] 0 of 0 SQL statements executed successfully
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/target/test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/UserTest.java:[26,15] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class User
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.UserTest

[ERROR] /home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/UserTest.java:[27,15] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class User
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.UserTest

[ERROR] /home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/UserTest.java:[28,15] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class User
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.UserTest

[ERROR] /home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/BTFileTest.java:[23,15] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class User
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.BTFileTest

[ERROR] /home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/BTFileTest.java:[25,15] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class BTFile
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.BTFileTest

[ERROR] /home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/UserTest.java:[26,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class User
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.UserTest

[ERROR] /home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/UserTest.java:[27,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class User
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.UserTest

[ERROR] /home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/UserTest.java:[28,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class User
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.UserTest

[ERROR] /home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/BTFileTest.java:[23,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class User
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.BTFileTest

[ERROR] /home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/BTFileTest.java:[25,31] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class BTFile
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.BTFileTest

[INFO] 10 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

/home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/UserTest.java:[26,15] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class User
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.UserTest

/home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/UserTest.java:[27,15] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class User
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.UserTest

/home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/UserTest.java:[28,15] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class User
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.UserTest

/home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/BTFileTest.java:[23,15] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class User
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.BTFileTest

/home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/BTFileTest.java:[25,15] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class BTFile
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.BTFileTest

/home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/UserTest.java:[26,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class User
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.UserTest

/home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/UserTest.java:[27,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class User
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.UserTest

/home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/UserTest.java:[28,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class User
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.UserTest

/home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/BTFileTest.java:[23,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class User
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.BTFileTest

/home/arg/workspace/JBTBackup/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/BTFileTest.java:[25,31] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class BTFile
location: class org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.BTFileTest


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 26 12:54:37 CEST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/172M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks for all comments, Tomas Herman

Comment: In your github repository I didnt find a src/main/java folder where all your code should be residing. Also if you locally have this code, then first try 'mvn compile'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move your application classes to src/main/java/... instead of src/main/resources, cause Maven assumes (convention over configuration) that your java classes are located in src/main/java. This means they will never be compiled.

Comment: you are correct, sir...stupid of me not to notice that myself, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Note that Maven already failed to compile the classes to be tested:

```
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] No sources to compile
```

And @Gopi's comment explains why this happened. You should put your code under `src/main/java` for Maven to see it by default.

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit import for the `User` class in your [`UserTest.java`](http://github.com/tomasherman/JBTBackup/blob/a6174b62ca60a9990ca395fa45200291ebe6c765/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity/UserTest.java) file, which implies in should be somewhere in the `org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity` package.

However, there's no such file in either [`src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity`](http://github.com/tomasherman/JBTBackup/tree/a6174b62ca60a9990ca395fa45200291ebe6c765/src/test/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity) or [`src/main/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity`](http://github.com/tomasherman/JBTBackup/tree/a6174b62ca60a9990ca395fa45200291ebe6c765/src/main/java/org/tomasherman/JBTBackup/Resource/Entity).

I can't see anything in your POM file to generate this class potentially (like hbm2java). Maybe you've forgotten to commit it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to invoke mvn compile test-compile, or just mvn clean install ?